# Action on Google Test Account

Tags: firebase-authentication, actions-on-google, google-home

Im virtually ready to send my Actions on Google App live for Google Home. It uses Account Linking to link a Google Account. I don't handle login as such, I just use the inbuilt routine to detect if the user is logged in and push them over to a Google Auth page which takes care of everything and I get the results back to generate a code.

The notes for submission say that if we're using account linking:

> Your agent requires account linking so you must provide a username and
>   password for a test account. Please make sure that any provided
>   accounts are not real user accounts. This information will only be
>   used by the review team, and will not be visible to users.

What is not clear at this step, is what credentials I give to the review team to be able to test. I don't process any logins. Do I need to enable Email/Password authentication in Firebase then or something and on my OAuth page request Username/Password then authenticating with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in how you're authenticating the user:

> push them over to a Google Auth page which takes care of everything

So you're expecting your users to login with some account (I assume you mean a Google account in this case) and you are either using the code that comes back as the auth code or getting the userid and using that to authenticate the user or something else along those lines.

Basically - you need to create whatever you expect them to do as if they were a user. If you're expecting your users to log in using a Google account - create a Google account for them to use. If you're expecting them to login with Email/Password auth in Firebase - set that up. But setup an account with however you expect your users to do so.

Comment: It really is as simple as that? Just set up a Google Test Account? Is there a procedure for this, or do I just go and setup a bog standard Google Account?

Comment: It really is as simple as that. :) They just need to have an account to test with and they don't use their own.

Comment: No specific procedure needed - just an account.